# Yii2 Custom ActionFilter not working with "only" defined as wildcard

Tags: php, yii2

I have:
RestModule > TargetController extends BaseController

in BaseController:

```
public function behaviors()
{       
        $behaviors['myfilter'] = [
            'class' => MyFilter::className(),
            'only' => ['rest/target/*'],
        ];
        return $behaviors;
}
```

but my filter working until "only" is not set or if I set TargetController actions names using "except"

Yii2 versin is 2.0.11.2 on php 5.5 debian8

Comment: You can't add expression like items to the 'only' array, only exact controller ID's

Comment: @SzántóZoltán, Yii2 Doc: Since version 2.0.9 action IDs can be specified as wildcards, e.g. site/*, I have ver. 2.0.11.2

Comment: I didn't noticed this feature until this question, so a big thanks to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since version 2.0.9 action IDs can be specified as wildcards, e.g. site/*. [yii2-doc](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-actionfilter.html#$only-detail)

If you want to attach filter with 'only' property and put IDs as wildcard, e.g. `target/*`, you should attach it as behavior to module class, not controller.
Try this in your RestModule:

RestModule:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    $behaviors['myfilter'] = [
        'class' => MyFilter::className(),
        'only' => ['target/*'],
    ];
    return $behaviors;
}
```